# Padding on div creating margin on preceding div media query

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm trying out different things with media queries right now. I want my tags to span 100% the width of the device. I am getting a margin on the right side of my image though. I think it is a result of the padding on the above div, because when I change the padding to zero the image spans the entire with of the device.

[This is what it looks like -with padding on the above div- and extra space on the side of the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbTpj.jpg)

[This is what the looks like -with no padding on the above div- and no space on the side of the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuVCy.jpg)

I would like no space on the side of the image but padding on the above div.

Here is what the code looks like in the media query section:

HTML:

```
<div class="paragraph">
    <p>Vaporwave is a genre of music/ art movement that originated on internet forums such as tumblr and reddit in early 2010. Because it was born online, it has no real origins and is considered the first genre of music to be completely globalized. The genre began as an aesthetic obsessed with 80's and 90's subculture. It was inspired by and contrived using glitch art, early digital graphic design, roman busts, tropical landscapes, japenese culture, and nostalgic television ads.</p>
</div>

<div class="image">
    <img src="images/skull.jpg" alt="vaporwave image of a skull">
    <p>Check out some more <strong>vaporwave art</strong> <a href="vaporart.html">>hurrr<</a></p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.paragraph {
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: .75em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    background: rgba(215,189,234,0.75);
}
.image {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Any thoughts on why padding would be causing a margin to occur?

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of it, the .paragraph is actually 100% + 20px (width + two * padding) which would be bigger than the .image (only 100%). If you use `box-sizing: border-box` on your elements, the padding will be included in the width which is probably what you want. Here's a js fiddle for reference:
https://jsfiddle.net/wwrvxc5y/1/

Comment: Yes this worked. That was the problem. I guess i thought padding was included in the width and margin was what was not. I didn't realize they both weren't.  Thanks for the help!